# Llenar comboBox con resultado de lineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy realizando mi primer plugin para Qgis 3 con Plugin Builder, y tengo el siguiente formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado tengo una tabla en sqlServer que contiene los siguientes valores.

```
Nombre      idLote
Situacion    1
Contexto     1
Detalle      1
Observacion  1
Situacion    2
Contexto     2
Detalle      2
Observacion  2
```

Como puedo llenar el comboBox a partir del valor que se ingrese en el campo lote, mostrando el nombre de la seccion segun el idlote que se ingreso en el lineEdit.
Intente hacerlo con pyodbc, no se si es la forma correcta pero fue lo que se me ocurrio, pero no me devuelve valores en la seccion.

```
import os.path
import sys,os
#sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python')
os.environ['PATH'] += r";C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\bin;"

# Examine new PATH environment variable

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QTextLine
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction,QMessageBox
import pyodbc

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .Guarda_Informes_dialog import SaveInformesDialog

#Obtengo la Lista de secciones segun el informe
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=-test;Database=Si-test;uid=Consulta;pwd=2017')

cursorLista= con.cursor()

######################################

class SaveInformes:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """

        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'SaveInformes_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = SaveInformesDialog()

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&GuardaInformes')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'SaveInformes')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'SaveInformes')


   # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('SaveInformes', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/Guarda_Informes/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Guardar Informe'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&GuardaInformes'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar

    def run(self):

        self.dlg.lote.text()

        sql = ("SELECT sec.Nombre as Seccion  FROM [inf].[Lote] lot \
                                                        inner join [Seccion] sec on sec.idInforme = lot.idInforme \
                                                        Where idLote = '%s'") % \
              (self.dlg.lote.text())

        cursorLista.execute(sql)

        for x in cursorLista:
            self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(str(x[0]))
            print(str(x[0]))
            QMessageBox.information(None, "valores", ",".join([str(x[0]) for x in cursorLista]))
            QMessageBox.information(None, "valores", "idLote={}".format(self.dlg.lote.text()))

        self.dlg.show()


        # Run the dialog event loop

        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:


            ordenValue = self.dlg.orden.text()

            nombreArchivoValue = self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()

            referenciaValue = self.dlg.referencia.toPlainText()



            #Guarda imagen en servidor

            self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("D:/temp/prueba.png")

            pass
```

Comment: ¿por qué limpias el combobox: `self.dlg.comboBox.clear()`?, no te parece contradictorio rellenarlo y despues limpiarlo, lo que debes hacer es limpiar y despues llenar.

Comment: Borre la linea de borrado del comboBox pero sigue sin traer los resultados de la seccion

Comment: ¿qué es `cursorlista`?

Comment: Es el nombre del cursor que esta ejecutando la consulta sql

Comment: imprime `x[0]` dentro del loop para estar seguro que obtienes resultados, si no hay resultados el combobox estará vacio.

Comment: que yo recuerde el simbolo "\" no esta permitido en un query.

Comment: Si lo ejecuto el plugin por primera vez no salen los datos en la ventana, pero cuando lo vuelvo abrir estan los resultados en la seccion

Comment: Entonces por alli esta el problema, no es el QComboBox, es la lectuta de la base de datos, depura esa parte.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81170/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-llenar-combobox-con-resultado-de-lineedit). @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas intentando cargar el QComboBox pero al no ser visible el dialogo el texto del QLineEdit esta vacio, tu debes rellenar el texto cuando el usuario rellena el QLineEdit, para ello puede usar la señal textChanged o editingFinished de QLineEdit, en el siguiente codigo muestro como hacerlo con textChanged.

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    ...
    self.dlg = SaveInformesDialog()
    self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
    ...

def run(self):
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        ordenValue = self.dlg.orden.text()
        nombreArchivoValue = self.dlg.nombreArchivo.text()
        referenciaValue = self.dlg.referencia.toPlainText()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("D:/temp/prueba.png")

def onTextChanged(self, text):
    if text:
        sql = ("SELECT sec.Nombre as Seccion  FROM [inf].[Lote] lot \
                inner join [Seccion] sec on sec.idInforme = lot.idInforme \
                Where idLote = '%s'") % \
              (text, )
        cursorLista.execute(sql)
        self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([str(x[0]) for x in cursorLista])
```

Comment: funciono perfectamente, no se como agredecerte por tu tiempo, muchisimas gracias